# Result showing that DTIME[T] is strictly contained in random-access NTIME[T]

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nondeterminism

I recall seeing a result showing that multi-tape DTIME[T] is strictly contained in random-access NTIME[T] for reasonably large T (so not the PPST proof with the $\log^\star$ sort of factors), but I can’t find it. Does such a result exist?